# How to redirect all URL requests to single php page and still play videos using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

How to redirect all URL requests to single php page with simple HTML5  element, but still allow that same page to play video file, through HTML5  element ?

Right now, i have a few half working solutions that would redirect/forbid, but not playing videos (like the source link have also absorbed rule and redirect / forbid).

can someone PLEASE help me with both solutions

1. HOW TO REDIRECT ALL pages / folders / files, to same single index.php
2. HOW TO FORBID ALL --||-- and only allow viewing videos from same index.php

My head will explode, i cant read and test them anymore.. :(

More details: 
i have VirtualHost: domen.com
folders:
    domain.com/player/      // with index.php main page
    domain.com/media/       // with forbidden media videos

index.php is simple page with HTML5  tag, that gets file name from argument and loads video from domain.com/media/

URL example:    domain.com/player/index.php?video=filename.mp4

```
<video controls autoplay>
    <source src="../media/<?php echo $_GET['video']; ?>" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Some of partial solutions from other stackoverflow posts:

1. Redirect solution that is not working: its redirecting all to index.php, but also video file is not playing (like i said like its redirecting source too???)

   `RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/player/index.php$
   RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^domain.com
   RewriteRule $ /player/index.php [R=302,L]`
2. Doesn't redirect

   `RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule http://domain.com(?!/player).* http://domain.com/player/index.php [R=301,QSA,NC,L]`

If i need to add something more, please tell me,
thank you all !!!

Comment: Anyone ?
Any partial solutions ?
thanks :\